# What is the correct casing when there are brackets involved?

Tags: meaning, capitalization

Just writing my own definition for some words in my spare time.

I have come across definitions such as:

> fatso
>
> (Discriminating) Somebody fat

I just put an extremely simple definition there. But what I am worrying about is the casing. Which of the following would be correct?

> (Discriminating) Somebody fat
>
> (discriminating) Somebody fat
>
> (Discriminating) somebody fat
>
> (discriminating) somebody fat

Which one would be correct punctuation usage?

Comment: @Kris Whoops, sorry. That was an error. I just fixed that.

Comment: I think the word you want is "deprecatory" or "disparaging" or "discriminatory" (= applying or favoring discrimination in treatment) rather than "discriminating" (= making a distinction : distinguishing [a discriminating mark] : discerning, judicious [discriminating buyers]). They may be listed as synonyms, but they're not fungible in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(I'm not sure) how to capitalize this sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46544/im-not-sure-how-to-capitalize-this-sentence)

Comment: @BillFranke It was just an example. I didn't actually use that.

Answer (score 2):

I think none of the words requires capitalization.

***fatso***
(discriminating) somebody fat

If you are also providing an example sentence, that sentence may follow normal capitalization and punctuation.

BTW, the category would probably be *(derogatory)* and not as you stated.

> ***fatso***
>   (derogatory) somebody fat
>   "*All the fatso could think of was food, food and more food.*"

Comment: This has the additional advantage that a person coming across the style for the first time would not be led to wonder whether **fatso** meant _somebody fat_ or _descriminating (against?) somebody fat_. That is, whether 'discriminating' was a classifying comment-clause (which it is) or part of (one alternative of) the definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To distinguish, some dictionaries reserve a special style (font-face, font-style, etc.) for the class descriptor.